# how to get data from a specific table html $_POST[] in the form PHP

Tags: php

In form I have two table in form, for example table#1, table#2. both tables are sent only one $_POST. How to get data form e.g table#1 ? Is it possible to select in some way in $ _POST ['table # 1']?

```
<form id="prepForm" action="" method="POST">
<table id="1" class="table tabele-conclusions table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lp.</th>
            <th>desc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><input name="row1_desc" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="2" class="table tabele-conclusions table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lp.</th>
            <th>desc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td><input name="row2_desc" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: "_both tables are sent only one $_POST_" How are tables sent via POST? Can you elaborate?

Comment: define `name` attributes of all your elements as array and use `name = data[table1]['name']....` like that

Comment: How is even possible for anyone to possibly understand what your issue is here, if you don't post any code... pawel1993.

Comment: After your edit, I can suggest you to read some tutorials on how data submission and forms work in HTML and PHP.

Comment: No need to target your "tables" here (since they are not available in $_POST anyways), your input fields all have a name, just use `$_POST['row1_desc']` and `$_POST['row2_desc']`

Answer (score -1):

Simple examples:

Html

```
<form action="/post.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="testinput" value="Hello world!" />
</form>
```

Php:

```
<?php
  echo $_POST["testinput"]; // Hello world!
?>
```

**Edit: When I gave this reply, there was no sample code in the question.**